# Are there ABC language level tags of some kind?

Tags: discussion, tags

Just arrived here at LL community and saw a comment mentioning **"A level"** being the most basic kind of official recognition. As far as I know, this is an European standard:

<kbd>[image: asking google about EU levels]</kbd>

Browsing other site questions, I met one [where OP states](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/can-i-understand-95-percent-of-cnn-and-talk-show-movies-anything-just-in-3-yea):

> I’m a between B1 and B2 level Right now.

And then [one commenter asks](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/can-i-understand-95-percent-of-cnn-and-talk-show-movies-anything-just-in-3-yea#comment4344_3649):

> what are B1 and B2 levels?

My questions are: how relevant are those categories? Do they need specific tags? I've researched for [level](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/level), `[a*]`, [europe](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe) tags but didn't find anything related.

Answer (score 3):

The CEFRL categories are a relatively popular method of measuring language proficiency. We have a question about them [here](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/440/85).

At the moment, we don't have CEFRL level-specific tags. However, I wouldn't be particularly *against* having CEFRL level-specific tags, but so far I don't believe we've had a need for them. It's possible that if we get too specific with the proficiency tags we'll get a lot more language-specific questions (something we don't want).